# Simple UITableViewCell casting fails intermittently

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that registers a `PaymentAddressTableViewCell` which has a method on it called `validate` which looks at the `cellType` enum and applies a specific validation to the text field in the cell.

```
let tableView = UITableView()
tableView.register(PaymentAddressTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PaymentAddressCell")
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
... more layout
```

I'm seeing in Fabric that sometimes the following cast fails. So far I've chalked it up to something internal to UIKit failing. It could also be a misrepresentation of line number since the app is compiled for production. But for the sake of this, let's assume it's not.

I started by changing the force unwrap to a `guard let` as you'll see below. That else case should never really hit. Casting is pretty simple...

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 1)
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PaymentAddressTableViewCell else {
        ... this should never really be hit
    }
}
```

Any idea what this might be or how I might avoid the cast failing?

Thanks

**Edit** `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PaymentAddressCell") as! PaymentAddressTableViewCell
    cell.textField?.returnKeyType = .done
    cell.textField?.delegate = self

    switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (0, 0):
        cell.fieldType = .cardNumber
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "5555123456789999"
        cell.textField?.keyboardType = .numberPad
        cell.textField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cardNumberChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    case (0, 1):
        cell.fieldType = .expiration
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "01/20"
    case (0, 2):
        cell.fieldType = .cvv
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "CVV"
        cell.textField?.keyboardType = .numberPad
        cell.textField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cvvChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    case (1, 0):
        cell.fieldType = .address
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "123 Main Street"
        cell.textField?.autocapitalizationType = .words
        cell.textField?.keyboardType = .default
    case (1, 1): // address line 2
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "Apt 3"
        cell.textField?.autocapitalizationType = .words
        cell.textField?.keyboardType = .default
    case (1, 2):
        cell.fieldType = .city
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "City"
        cell.textField?.autocapitalizationType = .words
        cell.textField?.keyboardType = .default
    case (1, 3):
        let dict: [(key: String, value: String)] = viewModel.statePickerOptions.sorted(by: {
            return $0.0 < $1.0
        })
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "State"
        cell.statesDataSource = dict
        cell.fieldType = .state
    case (1, 4):
        cell.fieldType = .zipcode
        cell.textField?.placeholder = "Zipcode"
        cell.textField?.keyboardType = .numberPad
    default: break
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `cellForRow(at:)` returns nil if the cell at the indexPath is not visible. So it shouldn't even be the cast that is causing the issue, but because you have a nil value. Explicity in pseudo code: `guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){ if let cell as?PaymentAddressTableView{//Hourray}else{//Cell of other class}}else{//there is no cell}`

Comment: How did you implement the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: @Sweeper Just edited original post with code

Comment: @Larne Thanks. I wonder if it's small devices where a cell might not be shown that's causing the crash if `cellForRow(at:)` is returning nil

Comment: @Larme I just ran my app in a iPhone 5 sim and every cell is visible in the view. 3 cells in the first section, 5 cells in the second section. Only thing is that sometimes a cell is covered up by the keyboard based on screen size but that function should never return nil.

Comment: In your for loop, you try to get the indexPath at [row:4, section0], which you don't have, no?

Comment: That for loop I posted is for the second section with 5 cells in it